# Many Time Attack

Tags: encryption, one-time-pad, key-reuse

How i can XOR these two cipher texts encrypted by using same key

First

```
315c4eeaa8b5f8aaf9174145bf43e1784b8fa00dc71d885a804e5ee9fa40b16349c146fb778cdf2d3aff021dfff5b403b510d0d0455468aeb98622b137dae857553ccd8883a7bc37520e06e515d22c954eba5025b8cc57ee59418ce7dc6bc41556bdb36bbca3e8774301fbcaa3b83b220809560987815f65286764703de0f3d524400a19b159610b11ef3e
```

Second

```
234c02ecbbfbafa3ed18510abd11fa724fcda2018a1a8342cf064bbde548b12b07df44ba7191d9606ef4081ffde5ad46a5069d9f7f543bedb9c861bf29c7e205132eda9382b0bc2c5c4b45f919cf3a9f1cb74151f6d551f4480c82b2cb24cc5b028aa76eb7b4ab24171ab3cdadb8356f
```

Comment: Um, what are you asking? You calculate the xor, um, by calculating the xor. It's easy to implement in most programming languages.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like part of a problem posted from the first week's assignment of the Cryptography 1 Coursera course.

Boneh outlines in his course material how XOR'ing two cipher texts encrypted with the same key result in a new cipher, similar to below.

$$
m_1  \oplus k = c_1 \\
m_2 \oplus k = c_2 \\
c_1 \oplus c_2 = m_1 \oplus k \oplus m_2 \oplus k = m_1 \oplus m_2
$$

And then you can use simple analysis to derive $m_1$ or $m_2$.

In the case of this problem, XOR'ing these two strings to derive a key won't give you the answer that you are looking for - instead, pay attention to Boneh's "hint".